# Is there any way to host the IDE in windows but the source and compile (GCC) on linux?

Tags: c++, linux, windows, ide

I'm trying to find way to remote connect to a Linux server that contains my source files, or even on a VM with Linux on my Windows PC.
The main thing I want is to be able to use an IDE on Windows to edit the code, and connect the remote host with the sources and GCC or remote into the Linux machine to do the compilation on there.

Comment: Which IDE would you like to use on Windows?

Comment: what ever IDE that will make it work

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Visual Studio (2017+) has a "Linux Project" template that uses SSH to compile remotely.
More info [here](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/linux-development-with-c-in-visual-studio/).

Comment: If its working this is amazing!!!
i will check it i hope its in the free version also

Comment: Yes it is in the community ver

Comment: i will try it , it is to good to be true

Answer (score 0):

You can perfectly use a VCS for this. Just create a `git` repository and always push your code to it. Then, you can let the remote server pull in the changes and compile the sources.

This is exactly what [build servers](https://searchsoftwarequality.techtarget.com/definition/Build-Server) do.

Comment: Sounds pretty annoying to have to commit whenever you want to build. This is absolutely what build servers do when you've finished developing, but typically you want a shorter circuit while you're actually playing around typing things in.

Comment: That's true. Another option (when using the VM on local method) might be to have a shared folder between the VM and the host where source files are available to both.

Comment: not good , i want to be able to debug the source code IDE in windows , running in Linux

Comment: @user63898 That is not what you said in your question.